# Error Opening Client Server- Java

Tags: java, client-server, client, server

I am writing a server program tries to guess a number that the client has.  The server receives a low and high number (300 apart) from the client, and uses the binary search algorithm a maximum of 9 times to try to determine the number.  I'm getting an error on some of the test cases "Error Opening Client Server".  When run individually, most of the test cases pass, but run in sequence they do not. I believe this is a problem with opening and closing the socket and server correctly, but can't seem to figure it out.  Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingServer {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try{
            ServerSocket server;

            server = new ServerSocket( 5150 );
            System.out.println("awaiting client...");
            Socket client = server.accept();
            System.out.println("client connected");
            Scanner in  = new Scanner    ( client.getInputStream() );
            PrintWriter  out = new PrintWriter( client.getOutputStream(), true );
            String first = in.next();
            int high = in.nextInt();
            int low = Integer.parseInt(first);

            boolean serverRun = true;

            while(serverRun == true)
            {
                    if(!first.equals("SHUT DOWN"))
                    {
                        System.out.println(low);
                        System.out.println(high);

                            int bNum = ((high - low) / 2) + low;
                            out.println(bNum);
                            System.out.println(bNum);
                            String temp = in.next();

                            if(temp.equals("high"))
                            {
                                high = bNum;
                                System.out.println(temp + ": ");
                                System.out.println(high);

                                i++;
                            }
                            else if(temp.equals("low"))
                            {
                                low = bNum;
                                System.out.println(temp + ": ");
                                System.out.println(low);
                                i++;
                            }
                            else if(temp.equals("won"))
                            {
                                System.out.println(temp);
                                serverRun = false;
                            }
                            else if(temp.equals("lost"))
                            {

                                System.out.println(temp);
                                serverRun = false;
                            }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        serverRun = false;
                    }
                }
            client.close();
            in.close();
            out.close();
            server.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the JUnit Test:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class GuessingServerTest {
    @Test
    public void testReflection() {
        Class<?> iClass  = GuessingServer.class;
        Field[]  iFields = iClass.getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field f : iFields) {
            if (!f.isSynthetic()) {
                assertTrue ( "Field \""+f.getName()+"\" should be private", Modifier.isPrivate( f.getModifiers() ));
                assertFalse( "Field \""+f.getName()+"\" can't be static",   Modifier.isStatic ( f.getModifiers() ));
            }
        }
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void startServer() {
        // run server
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GuessingServer.main( new String[]{ } );
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
    @Before
    public void waitTwoSecondsBetweenTests() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep( 2000 );
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test(timeout=3000)
    public void testA_WinningAfter1Try() {
        try {
            // run client
            Socket      socket  = new Socket( "localhost", 5150 );
            Scanner     scanner = new Scanner    ( socket.getInputStream() );
            PrintWriter writer  = new PrintWriter( socket.getOutputStream(), true );

            writer.println( "101 401" );
            // try 1
            int actual = scanner.nextInt();
            assertEquals( "Incorrect result", 251, actual );

            writer.println( "won" );

            socket .close();
            scanner.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail( "Error opening client socket" );
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail( "The server didn't return a value" );
        }
    }

    @Test(timeout=3000)
    public void testB_WinningAfter2Tries() {
        try {
            // run client
            Socket      socket  = new Socket( "localhost", 5150 );
            Scanner     scanner = new Scanner    ( socket.getInputStream() );
            PrintWriter writer  = new PrintWriter( socket.getOutputStream(), true );

            writer.println( "37 337" );
            // try 1
            int actual = scanner.nextInt();
            assertEquals( "Incorrect result", 187, actual );
            writer.println( "low" );
            // try 2
            actual = scanner.nextInt();
            assertEquals( "Incorrect result", 262, actual );
            writer.println( "high" );
            // try 3
            actual = scanner.nextInt();
            assertEquals( "Incorrect result", 224, actual );
            writer.println( "high" );
            // try 4
            actual = scanner.nextInt();
            assertEquals( "Incorrect result", 205, actual );
            writer.println( "low" );
            // try 5
            actual = scanner.nextInt();
            assertEquals( "Incorrect result", 214, actual );
            writer.println( "high" );
            // try 6
            actual = scanner.nextInt();
            assertEquals( "Incorrect result", 209, actual );
            writer.println( "high" );
            // try 7
            actual = scanner.nextInt();
            assertEquals( "Incorrect result", 207, actual );
            writer.println( "high" );
            // try 8
            actual = scanner.nextInt();
            assertEquals( "Incorrect result", 206, actual );
            writer.println( "won" );

            socket .close();
            scanner.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail( "Error opening client socket" );
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail( "The server didn't return a value" );
        }
    }

    @Test(timeout=3000)
    public void testC_PlayingARandomGame() throws IOException {
        final int    UPPER  = 200;
        final int    RANGE  = 300;
        final int    TRIES  =   9;

        final Random random = new Random();
        try {
            // run client
            Socket      socket  = new Socket( "localhost", 5150 );
            Scanner     scanner = new Scanner    ( socket.getInputStream() );
            PrintWriter writer  = new PrintWriter( socket.getOutputStream(), true );

            int low    = random.nextInt( UPPER );
            int hi     = low + RANGE;
            int number = low + random.nextInt( RANGE );

            writer.println( low + " " + hi );

            int     tries    = 0;
            boolean gameOver = false;

            while (!gameOver) {
                int guess = scanner.nextInt();
                if (guess == number) {
                    writer.println( "won" );
                    gameOver = true;
                }
                else {
                    if (++tries > TRIES) {
                        writer.println( "lose" );
                        gameOver = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        if (guess < number) {
                            writer.println( "low" );
                        }
                        else {
                            writer.println( "high" );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            socket .close();
            scanner.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail( "Error opening client socket" );
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail( "The server didn't return a value" );
        }
    }

    @Test(expected = IOException.class)
    public void testD_RunsLast_ServerShutsDown() throws IOException {
        try {
            // running client #1...shuts down server
            Socket      socket  = new Socket( "localhost", 5150 );
            PrintWriter writer  = new PrintWriter( socket.getOutputStream(), true );

            writer.println( "SHUT DOWN" );

            socket.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail( "Error opening client socket" );
        }
        waitTwoSecondsBetweenTests();

        // running client #2...should throw exception (server should have stopped)
        new Socket( "localhost", 5150 ).close();
        fail( "Socket should not connect after server was shut down" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server [accepts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html#later) only one client during its lifetime and the test class starts the server only [once](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) for all test methods in the test class. Either the accept() must happen in a loop or each test method must start the server anew.